# Camel Splitter XML DSL how to log message index

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using Apache Camel version 2.15.1. My route has a splitter which splits the body in chunks and each chunk is saved into database. I would like to log a progress of this route. Unfortunately `CamelSplitIndex` header is 0-based, how do I do "+ 1" using XML DSL?

```
<route id="insertInDb">
    <from uri="direct:listOfDataInBodyArrivesHere" />
    <split>
        <simple>${body}</simple>
        <log message="Insert ${header.CamelSplitIndex} of ${header.CamelSplitSize}" />
        <to uri="mybatis:insertData?statementType=Insert" />
    </split>
    <log message="Insert done" />
</route>
```

The output is

> Insert 0 of 3
>      Insert 1 of 3
>      Insert 2 of 3

My desired output is

> Insert 1 of 3
>      Insert 2 of 3
>      Insert 3 of 3

How do I achieve the desired output? I tried with `${header.CamelSplitIndex++}` with no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be `${header.CamelSplitIndex}++`

Comment: Thanks, it works! As a note, this unary operator is available from Camel **2.9**